# RSS to XML/CSV? PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv

I have a quick question in reference to changing an RSS url

http://www.bellyscarf.com/rsscategoryproducts.sc?categoryId=6

As you can see, it is in RSS/XML format, but what I need is to have it changed into a regular XML (like http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml)or CSV file so that I may load it into my shopping cart.

I've been using SimpleXML to do all the dirty work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What distinguishes between the XML which is RSS and the "simple" XML?

Comment: RSS **is** regular XML. Whether you want to "simplify" it or just get the data out of it, it's equally hard. Use an existing RSS-reader library like [PEARs `XML_RSS`](http://pear.php.net/package/XML_RSS/) or [`Zend_Feed_Rss` from the Zend framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.consuming-rss.html).

Comment: SimpleXML is a php class used to parse/read/write XML. As you can tell, I don't believe that my shopping cart will take an RSS feed/url - but it will definitely take CSV and XML. I guess my main question is how to turn the RSS feed into an XML or CSV file that I can input to my shopping cart?

Comment: Since you don't say what shopping cart accepts as input XML or CSV, we can't really answer that can we?

Comment: My error; I meant to ask what is the difference between XML which is RSS and "regular" XML?

Comment: I want whatever is easiest... either XML OR CSV... CSV to be safe. RSS to CSV

Comment: What is your desired output format *exactly*? Your question is like "I want my drink in a glass or a bottle--whichever is easiest" without saying *what drink you want*. I am downvoting question until you clarify.

Comment: I am looking to output in CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you are looking to transform one kind of XML document into another one, XSL is a good first choice.

However, you say nothing about what your final XML or CSV should look like, so we can't really advise one or another course of action.